# Can't access some websites using Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.04, networking, wordpress

Something's wrong with Ubuntu. Since I've upgraded to 13.10, I can't access some websites for no apparent reason.

I've tried everything imaginable to solve this problem :

- Made sure that MTUs are the same,
- Disabled IPv6 in both the network manager and used browsers,
- Deactivated my network keys,
- DMZed my computer,
- Used other DNS like Google and OpenDNS,
- Checked that no firewall was running my computer ...

And it's the same result. I even tried to reinstall Ubuntu a couple of times, but no luck.

The most annoying thing about it is I can't access wordpress.org! So, there's no way it could be an ISP restriction of some kind.

When I use a VPN, I can access pretty much anything.

I'm really frustrated because I have to use [wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/) very often.

Any clue?

ifconfig

```
adame@adame-ws:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:18:3d:b0:7c  
      inet addr:10.42.0.1  Bcast:10.42.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::226:18ff:fe3d:b07c/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:8024 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7966 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:684480 (684.4 KB)  TX bytes:616608 (616.6 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:8222 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8222 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:568269 (568.2 KB)  TX bytes:568269 (568.2 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:19:70:40:85:eb  
      inet addr:192.168.2.3  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::219:70ff:fe40:85eb/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1464  Metric:1
      RX packets:123705 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:98141 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:94963545 (94.9 MB)  TX bytes:10387470 (10.3 MB)
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   adame-ws

::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

tracepath wordpress.org

```
1:  adame-ws.local                                        0.092ms pmtu 1500
1:  192.168.2.1                                           1.300ms asymm  2 
1:  192.168.2.1                                           1.060ms asymm  2 
2:  no reply
3:  no reply
4:  no reply
5:  no reply
6:  no reply
7:  no reply
8:  no reply
... keep on going like that
```

ping wordpress.org

```
adame@adame-ws:~$ ping wordpress.org
PING wordpress.org (66.155.40.250) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- wordpress.org ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 9071ms
```

Comment: I'm not sure if i can help without you posting some more info. - Are you by any chance dual booting?
- What are your rig specs?
- Did you try using a directly line instead of wireless already? With not much to go by it's pretty hard to pinpoint your exact issues.

Comment: Have you tried disabling/ignoring IPV6 in your network settings? Is it only happening in Firefox?

Comment: Already tried that in both the network manager and the browser :) I still can't get to wordpress.org

Comment: what happens if you run 'sudo ifconfig eth0 down', and try just using wlan0? Or vice-versa...

Comment: You probably shouldn't have both wired and wireless active at once.  Have you tried chrome or a different browser?  Do you not have any IPv4 info in your /etc/hosts?  Also, as per Matt's answer, have your tried wget, or curl, lynx, etc.?

Comment: Even without the wired connexion, it's pretty much the same. And yes, I tried wget and curl, both just stuck and get timed out.

Comment: Disabling eth0 doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check **your router's** hardware firewall for block-site rules; you can access it by visiting the router's ip *from your browser* in the form 192.168.x.x, try:

- 192.168.0.1
- 192.168.1.1
- 192.168.1.25x etc.

Write `ifconfig` (ENTER) in a console (xterm is fine) and watch the form of the inet address camp, you will need to edit only the last digits to find your router's ip.
You will need to know the password and the user (ex. admin admin, password password, admin password ecc. if you left the default). If you don't know there is a list online, google it...
You *must* **own** the router. ;-)
**If** there is no firewall block - strange - run form a console `sudo nano /etc/hosts` and remove any line with wordpress inside. Do not edit other lines, it can cause software problems.
A diagnostic action is running `tracepath wordpress.com` to discover where is the block, if it is a total block and not an http-only block.
Let us know by commenting under here, you can be useful to the community.
Nice evening, I will help you if you need more help.

EDIT for Adame: I must use a solution valid for all users, so you will need patience, network problems are hard to solve.
Execute in a terminal:

> echo "127.0.2.X HOSTNAME" >> toadd.txt
>
> echo "127.0.0.1 localhost" >> toadd.txt

(replace hostname with the output of the `hostname` command and X with the end of your current IP, you can see it in `ifconfig`)
then edit /etc/hosts as root (use `sudo YOUREDITORNAME /etc/hosts` and add on top the content of toadd.txt).
Delete toadd.txt :)
Now the first problem should be fixed.
Check if your hosts file is like this:

> 127.0.0.1 localhost
>
> Y.O.U.R.I.P   YOURHOSTNAME

and a comment line.
Other argument.
The ping isn't a valid check because a modern and well configured server will discard your pings to avoid ping bounce network attacks. For example my ping fails on wordpress.
ICMP Ping is good only for well known servers!
**But**, tracepath shows that no intermediate server receives your ping, and this is strange, because after your router the ping gets lost but continues to "hop"... are you using the network of your factory? If it's it, you can be behind a blocking intermediate server and you will need to use a proxy.
If this isn't you case, let's continue by ignoring tracepath (the path changes always, but your network path appears to be faulty).
Do a next step and try to do from a terminal `wget wordpress.com` and after that `ls -lh`: if you see an **index file** in html format which is greater than 10kb (may change in future) **the problem is in your web browser** (bad extensions or misconfiguration), if you don't, try other two times.
If you get a good index file (try to open it with a browser by double-clicking it) and you can see the webpage, simply disable ALL extensions in your browser and after that reinstall it.
If you can't get a good index file the problem is in your network.
Here the hard procedure **if you didn't solve**:

- Disable any proxy set in your browser and remove any instance of Tor
  and Privoxy, or of other distributed anonymous network systems.
  Reinstall them *later* if they aren't the problem, they are good for
  your privacy.
- If it doesn't work change the DNS in your router (**not** in your PC) to Google DNS (in Google we trust & we find the DNS ip) and try. SUGGESTION: leave the Google DNS, they are always good.
- If it doesn't work let's do a last check you can try to use a **transparent** proxy (anonim are slow) to re-route your traffic to wordpress: if it goes a server in the newtork hop path is faulty or your ip range is banned. If it doesn't function you may have a block inside your network.
  It's the best I can do with the information you left, good luck. Let me know. :)
  PS: a suggestion, for a proxy list search on google and pick a proxy with LOW ping and HIGH uptime.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I know my way around Ubuntu, routers and stuff. That's why this thing is beating my * pretty bad.

I'll update the post to include the intel you asked for.

Comment: As you can see, nothing special in both the network config and hosts. tracepath seems to give back response, but when I try to browse the website, it just hangs for a while to give back a time out error.

Comment: Thanks to you for the clarification: your `/etc/hosts` file is bad! I will edit my post to correct this little problem and I will also add more instructions to locate the problem. Just a sec.

Comment: Sorry, missed to copy the two first lines on my /etc/hosts. I just updated it.

Comment: I've done all that, except for the proxy thing. I've never used one per say.

Comment: If you ever used Tor or a Web proxy (like Anonymouse), then you used a succession of proxy servers, also called "proxy chain". They re-route (and modify) your traffic and can be a good way to access blocked websites and protect your identity. Please note that the free proxy are unstable and can be object of attacks, so use them occasionally and for a short time; remember that each proxy *will* slow down your connection and will truncate it very soon if the end server can't answer. The Tor chain is always different, is crypted and can be better. If you need more help feel free to write.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you use wget from a shell to access the site? If that works and downloads the index page, then it's a problem with your browser.

Comment: Nope. If it try to wget the latest wordpress release, it just hangs for a while to time out ...

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any permanent solution to this particular problem. But thanks to @Lorenzo, I resolved to use a selective proxy system for the websites I couldn't access on Ubuntu.

I'm using Tor-browsing + AutoProxy on Firefox. Working perfectly :)

Comment: Good for you, and don't worry the problem may be temporary. I added a comment before (go up) that you should read before using any proxy. Bye.