# Can not access facebook and youtube and certain google sites

Tags: networking

I can not access certain sites like youtube, facebook etc. I tried to `ping www.youtube.com` but it gives me `ping: www.youtube.com: Name or service not known`. When I try to ping without www it works  `ping youtube.com`,

```
PING youtube.com (216.58.206.14) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from fra16s20-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.206.14): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=62.7 ms
```

Same happens for facebook. I tried both browser firefox and chrome, same problem. So what is wrong here and how to solve it?

Comment: This seems fairly common. https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/250228 https://askubuntu.com/questions/772640/unable-to-access-some-websites https://askubuntu.com/questions/364497/cant-access-some-websites-using-ubuntu-13-10 have you tried any of these solutions? Is this a new install, or has it just recently stopped working? Do the sites work from a live CD? Is your router configured correctly?

Comment: Everything was working just fine. But recently I installed few desktop environments like KDE, GNOME. Then switched back to unity. I think the problem started after installing KDE.

Comment: This guy had a problem with kde that turned out to be a misconfigured proxy https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=35245